# The pprof heap report displays raw memory addresses

Tags: windows-8, go, pprof

Following this guide http://golang.org/pkg/net/http/pprof/, i'm trying to look at the heap report. When i navigate to the appropriate url, this is what is displayed:

[image]

I tried this with ActivePerl, StrawberryPerl and the Perl coming with MSYS tools. What is the issue here?

Answer (score 2):

The output of the net/http/pprof package is best used with `go tool pprof`. If your server is listening on port 6060, you'll want a command like `go tool pprof http://localhost:6060/debug/pprof/heap`. There's an explanation of how to use the pprof tool at http://blog.golang.org/profiling-go-programs, which is linked from the net/http/pprof package docs.

If you're really interested in trying to read the output yourself, you can add `?debug=1` to the url you tried before - but I can't recommend it.